# Kubernetes: How to map service to a local port inside pod

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to map Kubernetes service to a specific port for a group of pods (deployement)?
E.g. I have service (just as an example)

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
```

And I want this service be available as http://localhost:8081/ in my pods from some specific deployment.

It seems to me that I saw this in K8S docs several days ago, but I can not find this right now.

Comment: Your service is exposing your deployment. It is a layer that sits on top of your pods. What do you mean by saying "I want the service be available as localhost:8081 in the pod"?

Comment: In all pods from deployment1 I want service (served by another deployment) be available on some local port

Answer (score 3):

It may be beneficial to review your usage of K8s services. If you had exposed a deployment of pods as a service, then your service will define the port mappings, and you will be able to access your service on its cluster DNS name on the service port.

If you must access your service via localhost, I am assuming your use case is some tightly coupled containers in your pod. In which case, you can define a "containerPort" in your deployment yaml, and add the containers that need to communicate with each other on localhost in the same pod.

If by `localhost` you are referring to your own local development computer, you can do a `port-forward`. As long as the port-forwarding process is running, you can access the pods' ports from your `localhost`. Find more on [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/). Simple example:

```
kubectl port-forward redis-master-765d459796-258hz 6379:6379 
# or
kubectl port-forward service/redis 6379:6379
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to build a prototype with direct injection of service. Access by DNS name is great but requires heavier configuration when you shift from development to production. I am building prototype where in dev mode you have all service that are required to your service run locally (not even dockerised), and in K8S you have same config but phisically services are on different cluster nodes (and yes, I know about DNS lookup).

Comment: What do you mean by "direct injection of service"? You normally would not be able to access services via `localhost` unless they are tightly coupled containers in a pod (ie. scheduled onto the same node).

Comment: As I said as far as I remember service can be proxied to a group of pods by K8S config, So it is no physically local

Comment: Ah I see, so by `localhost` you mean your own development computer?? If that's the case, check my amendment to the answer for **port-forwarding**. :)

Comment: @Denis The only way to inject external service access on localhost domain is using of `proxy` gateway sidecars. Just check [Multi-container patterns](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/multi-container-pod-design-patterns.html) and read about `Ambassador`. I hope you're really know what do you want.

Comment: `kubectl port-forward service/redis 6379:6379` this not works me for port forwarding service, but for me helps port-forwarding whole deployment (set of runinng pods) `kubectl port-forward deployment/redis 6379:6379`